# SQL Server stored procedure - update one table and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure that is coded similarly to the following:

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[procedure_name]

  @record_id int
, @record_value VARCHAR(MAX)

AS

BEGIN

UPDATE  dbo.table_1

SET table_1_record_value = @record_value
WHERE table_1_record_int = @record_int

END

BEGIN

INSERT INTO table_2 COLUMNS (table_2_record_id, table_2_record_value) VALUES (@record_id, @record_value)

END
```

And I'm getting a syntax error. I've never had to write a stored procedure for an application that would accomplish both an UPDATE and an INSERT statement together.

Comment: Maybe the word "COLUMNS" is excess. And what is the error you get?

Comment: After the "VALUES" the error is thrown on "@record_id"

Comment: 1. If the procedure isn't created yet, you will need to do `CREATE PROCEDURE`. 2. The update and insert statements are independent, no need to put them in their own `BEGIN...END` block unless there is a conditional. 3. `COLUMNS` in the insert statement might also be throwing things off - it is not necessary so remove it.

Comment: I should have been more clear - this is a procedure that already exists and I am just altering it.

Comment: And you should write the all error message's text.

Comment: Can you give us the actual SP, this abstraction is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by bbaird in the comments. Removing the BEGIN/END keywords fixed the problem. Thank you!

bbaird's full comment below:

1. If the procedure isn't created yet, you will need to do CREATE PROCEDURE. 2. The update and insert statements are independent, no need to put them in their own BEGIN...END block unless there is a conditional. 3. COLUMNS in the insert statement might also be throwing things off - it is not necessary so remove it.

Comment: Glad to help. Please copy my comment into your answer and mark your answer as accepted so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The answers of Jake and bbard are correct.
Below the code of your stored procedure:

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC [dbo].[procedure_name]

   @record_id int
   , @record_value VARCHAR(MAX)

AS

BEGIN

   UPDATE  dbo.table_1
   SET table_1_record_value = @record_value
   WHERE table_1_record_int = @record_int

  INSERT INTO table_2 COLUMNS (table_2_record_id, table_2_record_value) 
  VALUES (@record_id, @record_value)

END
```

For documentation of `BEGIN` and `END` look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)